# What does a very high cpu% in docker stats indicate?

Tags: java, multithreading, docker, cpu

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with a docker container and what seems to be some kind of problematic interaction with the hosted application.
I am running the docker container and I am monitoring `docker stats`.
I see that that `CPU%` gets up as high as `5000.02%`. What does that mean?
Note: I have **not** any configuration or tuning to the container. So does it mean it takes all the cores or only 1 core or what?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docker documentation by default, each container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles is unlimited.

You can limit it by [configuring default CFS scheduler](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler).

To troubleshoot the problem you need to ssh into the container and find out what process consumes all the cpu.

For doing that perform

```
docker exec -it YOUR-CONTAINER-ID /bin/bash
```

Then perform `top` command ([documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/top.1.html)). You'll be given with detailed statistics on every process running in the container having which you'll understand what causes the problem.

Comment: Isn't the only process in my container my hosted application? For some reason it seems that when I run it in docker it becomes a cpu hog. Standalone never had similar problem.

Comment: Probably yes. But I don't know your application, may be it starts multiple processes in the contained.

Comment: What is the difference with doing `top` on the server that hosts/runs the container?

Comment: When you run `top` on your host machine you'll get information about the processes running on the host machine. But the processes that are started within a container will not be listed there.

Comment: But I see something like `docker - process- threads A etc` from `top` in forking order

Comment: I mean I see a breakdown and not just 1 process for docker that is one row and consumes CPU and mem